# How to prevent this layout cycle?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, xaml, layout

[image]

The picture shows these little gaps. The big, blue **containers** between the gaps are content holders which widths are determined. The red border is the resizable **holder**.

So the two outer gaps describe the left and right *padding* of the red **holder**. The two gaps next to each container are the left and right *margins* of each **container**.

Everytime I resize the **holder** the `SizeChanged` event of it gets raised.

`gapsize = (holderWidth - summedUpWidthsOfAllContainers) / numberOfGaps`

I get the holderWidth via the `ActualWidth` (UIElement) property. I rebind (Silverlight hack) the MarginProperty of each **container** and the PaddingProperty of the **holder** everytime I the `SizeChanged` event is raised (`UpdateTarget` doesn't work in Silverlight and `INotifyPropertyChanged` is not available). This is done in the `UpdateMargins()` method which gets called in the `SizeChanged` event handler.

I try to prevent non-visible refreshing of the margins (less than one pixel) with comparing previous with new margins.

But with this approach I cause layout cycles from time to time. Now I just wanted to ask if there is a logic mistake. I've read [this](http://jeffhandley.com/archive/2008/09/26/silverlight-2-post-beta2-gotcha---layout-cycle-detected.aspx) blog and tried to solve it this way. But these layout cycles still appear.

I do this to center the contentholders (**containers**) everytime the holder gets resized. I know that a Grid with two columns would be a viable solution, as well. But the problem is that the red **holder** must be a WrapPanel, that in this case the second blue **container** jumps under the first one, if the **holder** gets too small to show them next to each other.

Comment: Sorry if i've misunderstood something but why don't you just use the wrap panel control as your 'red holder'?

Comment: @Dave S: I actually use a wrap panel for this purpose. It makes the columns stick to each other, though. This means I need to calculate these gaps everytime the holder gets resized to prevent this sticking.

Comment: I need to add one thing. The red holders width is determined through the windows size of the application. And as we know a wrap panels elements just use as much space as they **need**. I stretched this wrap panel, but I can't center the elements which are aligned horizontally. This is done via these gaps.

Comment: I'm not clear from your question what you are exactly trying to do.

Comment: My summary would be: I need a wrap panel, whichs width is determined through the window width of the application. Its elements are oriented horizontally. The elements of it shouldn't stick to each other, though. If it has two containers (blue) the wrap panel should have like two "GridColumns". And in there should blue containers must get centered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion changing anything on the visual tree in the SizeChanged event can end up giving you performance issues due to the multiple layout cycles that get invoked if you are not careful (this seems consistent with the issue you're describing).

If you need to layout content in a specific way I would advise creating a new panel and overriding the ArrangeOverride and MeasureOverride methods which are used during the layout cycle. You could use the existing WrapPanel source code (downloadable from CodePlex under Ms-Pl) and change the logic to layout the content as you require.

There are plenty of articles online about creating custom panels and the Silverlight layout cycle..

Sorry I can't help directly with your problem but hopefully this information can be of some use to you

Comment: Yes, you are right. I recognized that my checkings regarding old and new margins made it better. But still there are occuring layout cycles. Probably you're right. I'm gonna write a new panel. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's not hard to create a panel that will simply do what you want. Here's an example that gives an equal amount of space to each child:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace GapPanel
{
    public class GapPanel : Panel
    {
        protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
        {
            if (Children.Count == 0)
                return base.MeasureOverride(availableSize);
            // allot equal space to each child; you may want different logic 
            var spacePerChild = new Size(availableSize.Width / Children.Count,
                                         availableSize.Height);
            foreach (var child in Children)
                child.Measure(spacePerChild);
            var totalWidth = Children.Sum(child => child.DesiredSize.Width);
            var maxHeight = Children.Max(child => child.DesiredSize.Height);
            return new Size(totalWidth, maxHeight);
        }

        protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
        {
            if (Children.Count == 0)
                return base.ArrangeOverride(finalSize);
            var gap = (finalSize.Width - Children.Sum(
                       child => child.DesiredSize.Width)) / (Children.Count + 1);
            var spacePerChild = (finalSize.Width - gap * (Children.Count + 1))
                                / Children.Count;
            for (int i = 0; i < Children.Count; i++)
            {
                var child = Children[i];
                child.Arrange(new Rect(i * spacePerChild + (i + 1) * gap, 0,
                                       spacePerChild, finalSize.Height));
            }
            return finalSize;
        }
    }
}
```

You would use it just like a regular panel:

```
<my:GapPanel>
    <Button HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="200" Height="200">abc!</Button>
    <Button HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="200" Height="200">foo!</Button>
    <Button HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="100" Height="200">bar!</Button>
</my:GapPanel>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this one. That's been a good help and base for the panel I actually need.